# Align text in middle when there is a image in a row Bootstrap table

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table, but I can't seem to get the text to align in the middle because the image expands the row.

I have tried adding `vertical-align: middle` to `.table` in my CSS, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

#### Example

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/#&togetherjs=hy7S1lFDR3

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Hover Rows</h2>
<p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p> 
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Image</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
<td>john@example.com</td>
<td><img src="http://fullsoftwarepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Radmin-       server-and-viewer-3.5-Crack-License-key-Download.jpg" width=50></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mary</td>
<td>Moe</td>
<td>mary@example.com</td>
<td><img src="http://fullsoftwarepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Radmin-  server-and-viewer-3.5-Crack-License-key-Download.jpg" width=50></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>July</td>
<td>Dooley</td>
<td>july@example.com</td>
<td><img src="http://fullsoftwarepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Radmin-server-and-viewer-3.5-Crack-License-key-Download.jpg" width=50></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Forgive me if I have mispoken I'm still learning, but I thought table class was a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer

Twitter Bootstrap have a CSS class called `text-center`, you can simply use this one, as shown below.

#### Try this:

```css
CSS
.mid-align:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;
    
 }
```

```html
HTML

<div class="container">
  <h2>Hover Rows</h2>
  <p>The .table-hover class enables a hover state on table rows:</p>
  <table class="table table-hover text-center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-center">Firstname</th>
        <th class="text-center">Lastname</th>
        <th class="text-center">Email</th>
        <th class="text-center">Image</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="mid-align">John</td>
        <td class="mid-align">Doe</td>
        <td class="mid-align">john@example.com</td>
        <td><img src="http://fullsoftwarepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Radmin-server-and-viewer-3.5-Crack-License-key-Download.jpg" width=50></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="mid-align">Mary</td>
        <td class="mid-align">Moe</td>
        <td class="mid-align">mary@example.com</td>
        <td><img src="http://fullsoftwarepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Radmin-server-and-viewer-3.5-Crack-License-key-Download.jpg" width=50></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="mid-align">July</td>
        <td class="mid-align">Dooley</td>
        <td class="mid-align">july@example.com</td>
        <td><img src="http://fullsoftwarepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Radmin-server-and-viewer-3.5-Crack-License-key-Download.jpg" width=50></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

As for specificity, declaring a `style` attribute inside a tag overwrites the style written in your `*yourStyle*.css` file, so in most cases it is not the best practice to declare the style inside the HTML element, but it is surely acceptable (just added a small note).

Comment: This centers the columns, but i'm looking to center the row text in the middle. Here is a screenshot:

http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v399/lezgettdrunk/align_zpslfy7hp3q.jpg

Comment: I'm a little confused. When I run the code snippet link under your code it does look like the text is centered, but the hover is no longer there. I copied the code to bootstrap fiddle and there is no change. I tried adding class-"mid-align" and text-center to the code i'm working on and it shifts the row data the the right.

Comment: it is because bootstrap is not imported to the fiddle (you need bootsrap imported in your html file).. view my [working codepen here](http://codepen.io/liorgrs/pen/zrZKGE?editors=010)

Comment: Ahhh your right I was copying the code directly and forgot about that. I added the CSS code and works perfectly! Thank you so much!